# Characters of $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Just as the characters of $\mathbb{Q}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the adeles $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}$, which is the restricted product $\mathbb{R} \times \prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. Here restricted meaning that $(a_{\infty}, a_{2}, a_{3}, \ldots, ... )$ is in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ if and only if $a_{p} \in\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ for all but finitely many $p \in\mathbb{P}$.

Does it make sense to ask about (continuous) characters of $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$? If yes, has it been studied? I would like to learn about it and requesting some references.

Comment: The character group of a finite direct sum is the finite direct sum of the character groups, so this is $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^n$.

Comment: So, a character of $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ is $n$-tuples of the form $(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \ldots, \alpha_{n})$, where $\alpha_{i}\in\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{n}$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$? Any references to study this in context of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$?

Comment: Where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}$, yes. This is a simple consequence of the fact that Pontryagin duality $\text{Hom}(-, S^1)$, being a Hom functor, sends finite direct sums to finite direct sums (in fact it does much more than this too).

Comment: Is this intended? "$a_p=1$ for all but finitely many $p\in\mathbb P$"... that's not the definition of adeles I've usually seen. But I'm not very familiar with how people use adeles, so perhaps there is more than one useful thing to work with. The one i'm thinking of has $a_p\in\mathbb Z_p$ for all but finitely many $p$.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you... That was a typo indeed..

Comment: @QiaochuYuan If the character group of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{n}$ is the $(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})^{n}$, would not the characters of $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ end up in $(S^{1})^{n}$? Is that acceptable? I thought the characters had to take values in $S^{1}$?

Comment: @Gafar: that isn't the map that produces characters. You need to further compose with the product map $(S^1)^n \to S^1$. As an easier warmup, are you familiar with the fact that the character group of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ again, and the character group of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ again?

Comment: Ahhh.. I see what you mean... Thank you so much

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The character group of $\Bbb Q$ is not $\Bbb A_\Bbb Q$, but $\Bbb A_\Bbb Q/\Bbb Q$